# Assign a single cell to an array causes "Type Mismatch"

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

A fairly simple solution exists, I'm sure!
I have data held in a single Excel column that can have one to many entries.I need to add this to an array.
The code I have works well when there are 2 or more entries. 
However, I get a type mismatch when there is only one value. I've tried a number of work-arounds, but no success! Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Namez() As Variant

With Sheets("Names")
    Range("A1").Select
    Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
If Lrow = 1 Then ' Attempt at coding for a single value
  Namez = Sheets("Names").Range("A1").Value ' Here's where it errors
  Else
  Namez = Sheets("Names").Range("A1:A" & Lrow).Value ' Or here (before adding the LRow = 1 line)
End If
```

Comment: remove the `()` you cannot assign a single value to an array: `Private Namez As Variant`

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can do it like this way :

```
Option Explicit
Private Namez() As Variant

With Sheets("Names")
    Range("A1").Select
    Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

ReDim Namez(1 To Lrow)
For i = 1 To Lrow
    Namez(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was trying to avoid stepping through lines if possible. Is this the only solution that will work?